# Images formed due to lens made of 2 different materials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, lenses

[image]

The lens is made of 2 different materials, and we can conclude from the given diagram that the materials of refractive index **u1** are symmetrically placed with respect to the principal axis of lens.My book says that 2 images would be formed(one due to material *1*,and the other due to material *2*).But isn't it possible that a ray strikes material *1* and intersects a ray refracted via *material 2*?If I judge correctly,infinite no. of such images would be formed and since only two rays would be forming them,the intensity would be very,very less.Am I correct in my judgement?If not,where am I going wrong?Is it possible to ascertain that if those infinite images do form,they would all be formed on the principal axis itself?

Comment: Spaces after punctuation like `.` or `?` would make this much more readable.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience